# How to define a javascript functions which creates highcharts on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Basically I wanna define a function function makeChart(data) which creates a line chart with the data given.

I tried the following:

```
function makeChart(data) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'London',
            data: data
        }]
    });
};

alert("going to do it");

makeChart([1,2,3]);
alert("done");
```

The first alert message is printed, but the second one is not. Could it be I did not import some files? My html is currently:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src = "render.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I am new to how javascript. So please anyone explain how can I do this please?

Comment: render.js being the js file :-)

Comment: Are you including jquery?  Your makeChart call should be wrapped in a `.ready`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Comment: @Mark, if I use .ready thing, then it looks like this right? $().ready(makeChart), then how can I pass arguments?

Comment: $(function() {
  alert("going to do it");
  makeChart([1,2,3]);
  alert("done");
});

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function correctly, simply change

```
$(makeChart([1,2,3]);)
```

to

```
makeChart([1,2,3]);
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3420/)**

Comment: Hey Abdul, thank you very much for the answer. But I still have a problem. I did the change, and yeah it indeed works in the demo, but if I paste in my file it stops working anymore. I updated the question. Would you have another look please?

Comment: Have you included all the required js files? Jquery, highcharts.. And then defined a div with 'container' id

Comment: I find it's impossible to do just makeChart([1,2,3]), is it like Highchart has to be included in ready() thing? But if so, then it needs to be $().ready(makeChart), I can no longer pass arguments inside

Comment: You need to user $(document).ready(function() { makeChart([1,2,3]); makeChart([2,3,2]);  } );

Answer (score 1):

To call the function it's just `makeChart([1,2,3]);`.

The `$()` is the jQuery selector. For example, `$('#container')`.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you including jquery then highcharts?

Comment: No, no errors were reported. I just updated the answer :-( Am I included all the thing correctly?